# T4MVC How to Exclude Individual Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

Is there a way to exclude certain controllers or individual files from T4MVC?

Comment: Not really. Are you running into a specific issue? If so, you can start a discussion on http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/