# T4MVC Exclude File or Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4, t4mvc

I have a controller that is only built in Debug (using #if DEBUG) that I use to house some test methods that I don't want on the production server.

The problem I'm running into is that using T4MVC I get a derived class based on the controller with overloads of all the methods. As soon as I try to build in Release mode that base class and virtual action methods are no longer present and I get build errors.

Ideally I would like to be able to exclude the controller from T4MVC but I can't see a way to do that in the settings file and the answer to this question: [T4MVC How to Exclude Individual Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887728/t4mvc-how-to-exclude-individual-files) suggests its not possible.

Anyone know of a way to do it or can think of a good work around?

Answer (score 3):

**Use the T4MVC Attribute on your controller**

```
[T4MVC(false)]
public Controller ControllerToIgnore //...
```

Worked for my purposes (to exclude a specific controller from being generated).

From the [T4MVC documentation](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/wiki/Documentation#force-includeexclude-some-controllers)

Answer (score 2):

Consider separating your test methods and controllers into a separate project that depends on your production code. This way you would not need to have `#if Debug` stuff. I'm not sure what is your set up, but you can try using [NonActionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.nonactionattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) that is wrapped inside `#if !Debug` clause. So your production code would not run the methods as actions on your controllers. But this stinks with the wrong layout of the project.